# poseNet on react native causing FileReader error

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow, computer-vision, expo

implementing tensorflow with posenet into my expo project so once a user hits a certain pose it would result in the camera to take a picture and then user can press a button to upload it firebase. As soon as I open the camera I'm getting an error saying `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is not implemented]`. Odd thing is that nowhere in my code am I calling FileReader. I am using `blob` but that is to upload firebase but that is not triggered until a user pushes a button.

I am not even able to get the canvas to draw on the user or for posenet to console.log info such as users nose, ears, and so on. What am doing incorrectly?

Code that I have so far:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import * as posenet from "@tensorflow-models/posenet";
import { drawKeypoints, drawSkeleton } from "../utils/TfDrawingUtli";
import Canvas from 'react-native-canvas';


  const cameraRef = useRef();
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  const [TfReady, setTfReady] = useState(true);

  // tensor flow pose net
  const runPosenet = async () => {
    const net = await posenet.load({
      architecture: 'MobileNetV1',
      outputStride: 16,
      inputResolution: { width: 640, height: 480 },
      multiplier: 0.75
    });
    setInterval(() => {
      detect(net);
    }, 100);
  };

  const detect = async (net) => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      // Get Video Properties
      const video = cameraRef.current;
      const videoWidth = cameraRef.current.videoWidth;
      const videoHeight = cameraRef.current.videoHeight;

      // Set video width
      cameraRef.current.width = videoWidth;
      cameraRef.current.height = videoHeight;

      // Make Detections
      const pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(video);
      console.log(pose);

      drawCanvas(pose, video, videoWidth, videoHeight, canvasRef);
    }
  };

  // drawing a canvas
  const drawCanvas = (pose, video, videoWidth, videoHeight, canvas) => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    canvas.current.width = videoWidth;
    canvas.current.height = videoHeight;


    drawKeypoints(pose["keypoints"], 0.5, ctx);
    drawSkeleton(pose["keypoints"], 0.5, ctx);
  };

  runPosenet();


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      // tensorflow
      await tf.ready();
      setTfReady(true);
      console.log(` ======= TF is ready ==== ${TfReady} =======`)

    }
    )();
  }, []);
```

**upload to firebase code**

```
  const uploadImageAsync = async (uploadToFirebase) => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function () {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
      };
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.open('GET', uploadToFirebase, true);
      xhr.send(null);

    });


    const ref = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(user)
      .child('test image')

    const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
    blob.close();
    return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  };
```

**code inside return()**

```
<Camera ref={cameraRef} />

<Canvas ref={canvasRef} />
```

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/266 and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native might give some insights

Comment: I tried everything they mentioned out and getting same error. I have tensor flow for react native installed with everything they would require for a managed expo project